# Passing parameters into Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I've built a shiny application that allows users to import genetic data, and visualize it. I want users to be able to pass in the path to their data as a parameter into the server. Is there any way to do this? The path would simply be a string that is passed into the server function.

The reason I want this passed in as a parameter, and not some other solution, is I am currently creating an R package of this application, and I will have a function within the package that will launch the application.

This function will look something like this:

```
runMyApp <- function() {
  shiny::runApp(system.file("myapp", package="mypackage"))
}
```

Is there any way for me to pass a parameter into this runApp function, which in turn is passed into the server?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a discussion about this in the [shiny issues page](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/440). The solution there is to save the parameters in the global environment,

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested this extensively, but it seems to work.

Define shiny's `ui` and `server` as desired in `inst/myapp.R`
(I assume the variables have these names),
but do *not* call `shinyApp`.
Then in your package you can define a function like:

```
launch_app(param, ...) {
  file_path <- system.file("myapp.R", package = "mypackage")
  if (!nzchar(file_path)) stop("Shiny app not found")
  ui <- server <- NULL # avoid NOTE about undefined globals
  source(file_path, local = TRUE)
  server_env <- environment(server)

  # Here you add any variables that your server can find
  server_env$test_param <- "test"
  server_env$param <- param

  app <- shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
  shiny::runApp(app, ...)
}
```

Then any function inside your `server` should be able to see `param` and `test_param` and use it.

This also has the added advantage that all functions in your server will be able to use any unexported function from your package.

[Here's an example of how I do it in my package](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/tree/master/inst/ssdtwclust), with the launching function defined [here](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/blob/master/R/SHINY-ssdtwclust.R).

Comment: With this solution, does runApp need to be inside launch_app? Or could launch_app (renamed appropriately) return app to a calling script that then calls runApp on it?

Comment: And why hasn't this answer been chosen or upvoted? It seems less ugly than the ones recommended at the issues link in the comment to the original question.

Comment: You can certainly adapt the function as you desire, the key really is passing `local=TRUE` to `source`. I'll cross-post to github to see what they think.